# Are mental objects timeless?

Tags: epistemology, ontology, knowledge, dualism, knowledge-representation

Let's suspend for a moment the How? of the body mind problem and suppose an ontological paradigm where there are two classes of objects: *mental* and *physical*. Also that physical objects are spatially and temporally extended while mental objects are not. Physical things are the objects of everyday experience, and *information*. Information is physically expressed knowledge e.g. a book or memory. Mental objects are concepts, abstractions, and knowledge. True knowledge is a valid set of interconnections linking concepts, e.g. man and father, or modus ponens.

**All** knowledge exists simultaneously, but it can only be expressed in the physical if the necessary spatiotemporal structures exist. Thus information is built up over time following the pattern set by knowledge but also informing what knowledge may be expressed. This means that there are two modes of thinking: purely mental where a certain chain of conceptual relations is brought to attention, and physical thought where particular structures are activated or created. It also means that some concepts are more basic (primitive) and others are derivative.

I believe that dualism is a necessary structure to the creation of information, and a basic concept to experiential knowledge. However, we can return to monism by specifying the physical as a substructure of the mental, information is a cohesive linkage of concepts. But note that the mental may be seen as a product of the physical, provided only that *incorrect knowledge* may be so produced as exemplified by a state of confusion or the expression of untruth...

**Question: Has any philosopher asserted that knowledge is atemporal, or made this distinction between knowledge and information?**

**Edit:** "knowledge" here are closely related to what can be discovered by Plato's anamnesis. In fact the only difference is that the base substance can be mental or physical (or more precisely, both). The caveat is that the *knowledge* of what I will eat next Friday can only become *information* once the physical (spatiotemporal) structure "next Friday" becomes realized. So there are two basic assertions in question here: 1) All knowledge exist always, and 2) There is a distinction between knowledge and information.

Knowledge can be experienced but not communicated or memorized. Information can be communicated but can only exist contingent on supporting spatiotemporal structure. Knowledge can be accessed at any time, but information exist in a temporal niche. Knowledge cannot be created while information is created by agency such as physical process or human intellect.

Comment: You can split the whole world in two if you wish. Analyzing problems can be a helpful tool to understand them. Decoupling a system in fundamental parts and syntetizing after that improves understanding but, the fact remains: there is no single thing standing alone. All is related. Even human fancy needs a human been to stand. To think that your dreams exists without you is nonsense.

Comment: When you think of it , as says Woody,  “Eternity is awful long time, especially towards the end.”.

Comment: Plato https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamnesis_(philosophy) Many have suggested mind is primary and matter secondary, such as Mahayana Buddhism. There are many well established problems with your views, like Elizabeth of Bohemias critique of substance dualism. I would note modern physics is property dualist though (mass/info). Neoplatonism about mathematics is still quite popular, but creates more questions than it answers

Comment: Aside from the mental and physical there is also the abstract. It is non-physical like the mental (in idealism or substance dualism), but unlike it lacks causal powers and is timeless. A geometric triangle is timeless and causally inert, my thought of it is there when I am doing a demonstration this hour and gone the next, and has causal effects on paper if I am writing it down. Lumping together the mental and the abstract is what Frege and Husserl called [psychologism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/psychologism/) and criticized fiercely.

Comment: @Conifold "mental" is used here at a level of distinction between monistic and dualistic conceptual frameworks while you are using it at a lower level of distinction that is a sub-class of the previous. Also see edit.

Comment: @CriglCragl see edit.

Comment: Isn't your knowledge vs information dichotomy just a reformulation of abstract vs mental (in the usual sense), scholastic universals *ante res* vs *in rebus*, or even Plato's Forms vs embodied form-copies if we want to go all the way. SEP has a [long prehistory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/information/#HistTermConcInfo) to modern information talk, so you may want to focus it some more.

Comment: @Conifold I'll give that some thought. Though I'll point out that an abstract can be knowledge or information depending on whether a physical instantiation has been made.

Comment: Tegmark who created this https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/evwj9p/researchers-created-an-ai-physicist-that-can-derive-the-laws-of-physics-in-imaginary-universes is a mathematical platonist, and wrote The Mathematical Universe. I assume he distinguishes between universals & particulars. This may rapidly go into mathematics humans cannot visualise https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/evwj9p/researchers-created-an-ai-physicist-that-can-derive-the-laws-of-physics-in-imaginary-universes I like Karl Friston on what knowledge is https://youtu.be/TcFLQvz5uEg You make loads of unjustifiable assumptions